# Unable to get instance of RenderingContext

Tags: websphere-portal

I am facing problem in fetching the Rendering Context in Portal Theme of WPS 8. The following is the code snippet, that I used:

```
RenderingContext rc = (RenderingContext) request.getAttribute(Workspace.WCM_RENDERINGCONTEXT_KEY);
rc.getPath();
```

When I am using the above code snippet I am getting Rendering Context as `null`. I want to get the Current WCM path from the browser URL, but I am getting `null`. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: I have added below code then I able to get the instance of RenderingContext.  final Object o = request.getAttribute( Workspace.WCM_RENDERINGCONTEXT_KEY ); 
final RenderingContext rcjsp = ( o == null ) ? workspace.createRenderingContext( request, response, new java.util.HashMap() ) : (RenderingContext)o;
     String html = workspace.render(rcjsp, libComp);

Comment: but after adding above code I am getting below error:   R java.lang.NullPointerException
[4/24/14 17:44:45:311 IST] 00000054 SystemErr     R  at com.presence.connect.business.ServletContext.loadURL(ServletContext.java:746)
[4/24/14 17:44:45:311 IST] 00000054 SystemErr     R  at com.presence.connect.business.ServletContext.assembleRequest(ServletContext.java:715)
[4/24/14 17:44:45:311 IST] 00000054 SystemErr     R  at com.presence.connect.business.ServletContext.<init>(ServletContext.java:147)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below steps to create a rendering context.

---

repository = WCM_API.getRepository();

Workspace workspace = repository.getWorkspace(User, Pass);

```
// Create the rendering context                                      

RenderingContext renderingContext =
```

workspace.createRenderingContext(request, response, new

HashMap(),"http://localhost:10039/wps","connect");

---

Also, should set a render content as shown below. Then, only the render path will get displayed :

---

renderingContext.setRenderedContent(siteArea);

System.out.println("getPath: " + renderingContext.getPath(true));

---